# select data from second table if condition match from first table and limit data as a whole

Tags: mysql, merge, limit

```
TABLE ss contains column a)vendor b)affiliate c)salests d)orderid
TABLE sf contains column a)vendor b)affiliate c)salests d)orderid (exact same column with ss)
```

I need to select all data from ss and union data from sf when ss.vendor=ss.affiliate and ss.orderid=sf.orderid
I tried a lot for merging but couldn't.
I also need to LIMIT selection from offsaet say 100 from offset 101

Tried myself and from different tutorials, but couldn't find anyone working.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ss.vendor, ss.affiliate, ss.salests, ss.orderid
FROM ss

UNION ALL

SELECT sf.vendor, sf.affiliate, sf.salests, sf.orderid
FROM sf 
INNER JOIN ss on ss.orderid = sf.orderid
WHERE ss.vendor = ss.affiliate


LIMIT 100, 10
```

This will return rows 101-110

Comment: This just adds column from table sf. I need to retrieve data from both table. Once more time, all from ss table, retrieve data from sf if ss.vendor=ss.affiliate and ss.orderid=sf.orderid.

Comment: that selected the data. Thank you. But It needed to supply selection criteria two times for ss table. One for direct selection and one for joining with sf. Can't we union based on first result ?